# Core graphics filling only a part of my figure

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics

When i try to fill a figure, it only fill the arc. Here a picture to understand: 
[image]

I'd like to fill also the rectangle under the arc and i can't understand why it doesn't.

Here is my code :

```
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, wormBorderColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, wormFillColor);

    //Tracer la ligne de gauche
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, leftX, startingY);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, leftX, startingY-wormHeight);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rightX, startingY-wormHeight);
    CGContextAddArc(context, centerX, startingY-wormHeight, echelleSize/2, 0,M_PI , 1);


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rightX, startingY-wormHeight);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rightX, startingY);


    //CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Thank you. Please excuse my poor english and my poor core graphics knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the fill to work correctly, you need to have a closed path.  Every time you do a `CGContextMoveToPoint`, you break the path.   Try removing the `CGContextMoveToPoint` for the arc and the second side of the rectangle.  If the arc and the rectangle don't match, you may need to flip the start and stop angles in the `CGContextAddArc`, as it is likely starting and ending at the wrong points.